# Weights in scikit-learn metric functions

Tags: scikit-learn, data-science

Most of the `scikit-learn` metric functions have an option to take into account sample weights. What is the purpose or use case to use this options? Unbalanced classes?

How are they handled in for example `accuracy_score` or `log_loss`?

Comment: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#classification-metrics

Comment: Without weights every sample contributes equally to the metric. With weights one can let contribute some samples more or less than others. A use case is to reduce the contribution of less trustworthy or less interesting samples. Though, strictly speaking, this is not a programming question :)